# tomcat server install(This address is already in use)

Tags: tomcat

Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 minutes 1 second)

Comment: Deployment and starting aren't the same thing as installing.

Comment: Please read [ask]: dumping an error message does not qualify as a question. Please edit your question, or better, search for the error message yourself, which you will find all over. It's a quite common problem that has a lot of explanations already elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

It seems like **JVM** is unable to **bind** to the **port** mentioned in the **tomcat** configuration. You can find the process which is locking it and kill that process or you can change the listen port for your tomcat.

> Assuming you are using default port **8080**

Unix/Linux Command to check if the port is already in use:

```
netstat -pant | grep "8080"
```

Change the tomcat configuration to listen on different port:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```